# I want to install MongoDb 3.6 passively without including Compass

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDb 3.6.2 community in passive mode. I do not want to include MongoCompass. I cannot seem to find an option in the documentation for this.

Comment: Hi Brian, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask what you mean by _passive mode_?

Comment: msiexec has a passive mode which all you get is the progress bars

Comment: it is called silent mode. see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#install-mongodb-for-windows) But there is no comment on how to exclude compass.

Answer (score 0):

SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS="0"
This parameter was added in version 3.6.5 I believe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by passive but in the installation process you will get something like this

[image]

Hope this helps